How to formally set up a probability/statistics problem?
I am learning probability theory at the moment, and recently when I tried to apply what I know to a real life statistics problem (perhaps ill-advised, since I haven't studied statistics itself), I was told by a friend who knows probability and stats much better than I do that I was essentially doing it completely wrong. However, my error was not mathematical per se, but rather it was in the way I was setting up the problem and applying mathematics to the real world. This is what I would like some help with.
As a toy example, suppose that you want to do some statistics on people's heights, and so you want to model people's heights with some sort of random variable. Now, I know a random variable to be a measurable function into the real numbers, so, naively, I imagined that this would be done in the following way: our random variable is the function $X : \{\text{people}\} \to \mathbb{R}$, which assigns to each person their height (a real number). We put the discrete $\sigma$-algebra on $\{\text{people}\}$, so $X$ is a measurable function. Then we can ask questions about the mean and expected value of $X$, the probability of someone having a height $h$ which lies in a given interval $(a, b)$ in $\mathbb{R}$, etc.
My friend told me that while I could do it this way, this is very odd and basically never how you would set up a statistics/probability problem. Rather, you would have a collection of random variables $X_i$ indexed by the set of all people, with each $X_i$ representing the possible heights of person $i$. These random variables are expected to all have the same domain (though I am not sure exactly what it should be), and in general should be i.i.d. From this set-up you then proceed to tackle the problem.
This was very unintuitive to me! Had my friend not told me, I would not have figured out that this is the way you are meant to do it. But I still don't feel that I have a good general sense of how one takes a real-world (or purely mathematical!) question and formally sets it up as a statistics/probability problem. Can anyone help me with this, or point me to resources which explain in detail?

The idea is to model each single person as a random variable having multiple potential heights. Imagine a single coin; it is modeled as a single random variable $C$ that has potential tosses $0$ or $1$. In this modelling scheme, the random variable is frequently the identity function so in particular the domain is the same as the codomain.

It depends on what you want to do. There is nothing wrong with your approach, except you need a probability measure…are you assuming a single person is drawn equally likely from the population? If all you want to do is talk about a single random variable then your way is best. The “statistics” field can be viewed as a more narrow class of probability problems, often involving the estimation of some parameter based on iid samples.

Since the $n$ people's heights are each in $\mathbb R$, you are presumably going to want your sigma algebra to be the Borel subsets of $\mathbb R^n$.  Knowing this may reassure you that you have a foundation for your statistics, but it will not really help you with the statistics themselves.

The short answer to your question is "it depends on what you want to do" (as I stated in my comment). Here is a longer answer that may be what you are looking for.
Situation: Suppose we have a population of $k$ people with heights $\{h_1, h_2, ..., h_k\}$.  We want to model the situation of picking $n$ people from this population in a way that we can "do probability" or "do statistics." We may want to fully specify the model even down to the $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ details.
The following models all use a finite sample space $\Omega$ and sigma algebra $\mathcal{F}=Pow(\Omega)$ (the set of all subsets of $\Omega$), which means all functions $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are automatically random variables (Borel measurable functions).
Model 0 -- Picking just one person: This is the model you proposed. Define $\Omega = \{1, 2, ..., k\}$ as the sample space, which indexes which single person we pick. The sigma algebra is $\mathcal{F}=Pow(\Omega)$. The probability measure $P:\mathcal{F}\rightarrow[0,1]$ is the one where each person is picked with equal probability $1/k$, that is, $P[\{i\}]=1/k$ for $i \in \{1, ..., k\}$ (and so $P[A]=|A|/k$ for $A \subseteq \Omega$). We have a single random variable $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$X(i)=h_i\quad \forall i \in \Omega$$
This random variable $X$ is the height of the random person we pick. Assuming heights $\{h_1, ..., h_k\}$ are distinct, we note that $X$ takes values uniformly over $\{h_1, ..., h_k\}$, so $P[X=h_i]=1/k$ for $i\in\{1, ..., k\}$.
Model 1 -- i.i.d. sampling of $n$ people (with replacement): Fix $n$ as a positive integer, being the number of samples.  Let $\Omega = \{1, ..., k\}^n$ be the set of all $n$-tuples $(z_1,..., z_n)$, where $z_i \in \{1, ..., k\}$ denotes the particular person we pick on sample $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$.  Define $\mathcal{F}=Pow(\Omega)$ and $P:\mathcal{F}\rightarrow [0,1]$ as the probability measure where all $k^n$ tuples are equally likely. For each $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$ define a random variable $X_i:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by
$$ X_i(z_1, ..., z_n) = h_{z_i} \quad \forall (z_1, ..., z_n) \in \Omega$$
The value $X_i$ is the height of the random person chosen on sample $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$. It can be shown that $\{X_1, ..., X_n\}$ are indeed independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.). Note that this model allows picking the same person more than once, but if the population size $k$ is much larger than the number of samples $n$ then duplicates are unlikely to happen. Note that each $X_i$ has the same distribution as the $X$ variable of Model 0.
Model 2 -- sampling $n$ people (without replacement): Here we must assume $n\leq k$. Now $\Omega$ is the set of all $n$-tuples $(z_1, ..., z_n) \in \{1, ..., k\}^n$ that do not have repetitions (so this sample space is a subset of that of Model 1). Define $\mathcal{F}=Pow(\Omega)$. Define $P:\mathcal{F}\rightarrow[0,1]$ as the probability measure where all $n$-tuples in $\Omega$ are equally likely. For each $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$ we define random variable $X_i:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by
$$X_i(z_1, ..., z_n) = h_{z_i} \quad \forall (z_1, ..., z_n) \in \Omega$$
It can again be shown that each $X_i$ has the same distribution as $X$ from Model 0. However, the $X_1, ..., X_n$ variables are no longer mutually independent. Nevertheless, if the population size $k$ is much larger than the number of samples $n$, people sometimes  view these variables as being "approximately i.i.d." so that they can apply results that are known to hold for i.i.d. random variables.
Model 3 -- i.i.d. magically creating $n$ new people: This is your friend's model. The sample space, sigma algebra, and probability measure are the same as Model 1. Also, the $X_i$ random variables are the same as Model 1. However, for each new sample $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$, we magically create a new person and choose that person's height independently and uniformly over $\{h_1, ..., h_n\}$. We are not actually picking people from the population, rather, we are independently creating new people with the same height distribution as the original population. In this way, we can view each new sample as a "new and distinct person" (unlike Model 1 where we must accept the possibility that the same person may be chosen more than once).

When the population size $k$ is much larger than the number of samples $n$, the Models 1, 2, and 3 can be viewed as being similar. For precision, it is useful to distinguish these models rather than assume they are all the same. Note that some statistical techniques require i.i.d. random variables. However, not all statistics problems require i.i.d. random variables.  The non-i.i.d. situation of Model 2 (sampling without replacement) is important and can be analyzed with other techniques (such as by using properties of the hyper-geometric distribution). This is good news because in many real-world situations the population size $k$ is NOT much larger than the number of samples $n$, so our samples can be highly dependent on each other.
